# rails has_many relationship (4 models) and how to access in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, has-many-through

I have 4 models: transac, transac_data, item, dvd_details

```
class Transac < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transac_datas
  has_many   :items, :through => :transaction_datas
end

class TransactionData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :transaction
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :transaction_datas
  has_many   :transacs, :through => :transaction_datas
end

class DvdDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Now in the "transac" view, I need to access stuff from all these models like:

```
<td><%=h transac.status %></td>
<% transac.transaction_datas.each do |td| %>
  <td><%=h td.item_type %></td>
<% end %>

<% transac.items.each do |item| %>
  <td><%=h item.item_type %></td>
<% end %>
```

BUT I also need to access some info from the "DvdDetails" model which is the "furthest" away from transac.

I realized that doing something like this wouldn't really work:

```
class Transac < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transac_datas
  has_many :items, :through => :transaction_datas
  has_many :dvd_details, :through => :items, :through => :transaction_datas
end
```

and do this in the index of "transac" view

```
<%=h transac.dvd_details.name %>
```

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, with [Ian White's nested_has_many_through plugin](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through), you can daisy-chain has_many throughs the way you want.  Just install the plugin like so:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through.git
```

Then setup your model like this:

```
class Transac < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transaction_datas
  has_many :items, :through => :transaction_datas
  has_many :dvd_details, :through => :items
end
```

This should do what you need.

**UPDATE:** This question has come up a few times recently. I wrote an article, [nesting your has_many :through relationships](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/), to explain in detail.  It even has an accompanying example application on GitHub to download and play around with.

Comment: PS - nested has_many :through associations are like beer - enjoy in moderation :)

Comment: Interesting, somebody down-voted my answer even though it works perfectly, and they didn't offer a solution of their own.